# Ncrack:brute forcing with sock4 or 5 helps?

Tags: syntax

Ncrack:brute forcing with sock4 or 5 helps?i have a slow pc and i found this:

```
--proxy <type://proxy:port>: Make connections via socks4, 4a, http.
```

would be --proxy socks5://120.200.200.125:9150

helps?
thank u

Answer (score 1):

It will not help.  If the bottle neck in performance is your slow PC, changing the route of your traffic to the destination will not change the performance of your PC.

Using a proxy adds an extra hop in between you and the destination, so from a performance perscpective, it will actually have a negative impact (more latency).

Comment: very logical answer thanks,you know i just finish the test and is a bit faster with 1% faster,but boss is there something to make ncrack much faster for windows os?i know u can use knu parallels for linux os etc...

Comment: more parallels?if i use more then 20 paralles...i get nsock errors,timouts etc